# GMap.NET set Marker with TextBox Text and not with the Latitude/Longitude C#

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, gmap.net

i need help with the GMap.NET.

I have this Code to set a Marker with Latitude and Longitude: `GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(48.8617774, 2.349272), GMarkerGoogleType.red_dot);`

And i want to have something like that: `GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(textbox1.text), GMarkerGoogleType.red_dot);`

I want to get the Adress with a TextBox like "Lincolnstreet" and not with the Latitude and Longitude like in my first example. I searched hole internet for my problem but i found nothing. I'm a study and i need this Code to become finish. I hope you Guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NuGet package [GoogleMaps.LocationServices](http://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleMaps.LocationServices).
 It uses Google's REST API to get lat/long for a given address and vice versa, without the need for an API key.

```
var address = "Stavanger, Norway"; //Use textbox value textbox1.text

    var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
    var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(address);

    var latitude = point.Latitude;
    var longitude = point.Longitude;

    GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(latitude, longitude), GMarkerGoogleType.red_dot);
```

Comment: Thanks ! best Resulution in the hole Internet. This Plugin saves me from work, it does all Automatic. Thank you very well ! :)